# Haskell instance of `bind` for a custom type

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I'm trying to create an instance for bind operator `(>>=)` to the custom type `ST a`

I found this way to do it but I don't like that hardcoded *0*.

Is there any way to implement it without having the hardcoded *0* and respecting the type of the function?

```
newtype ST a = S (Int -> (a, Int))
    
-- This may be useful to implement ">>=" (bind), but it is not mandatory to use it
runState :: ST a -> Int -> (a, Int)
runState (S s) = s
        
instance Monad ST where
      return :: a -> ST a
      return x = S (\n -> (x, n))
       
      (>>=) :: ST a -> (a -> ST b) -> ST b
      s >>= f = f (fst (runState s 0))
```

Comment: Try replacing the `Int` with a type parameter. `newtype ST s a = S (s -> (a, s))`. This will force you into coming up with a correct implementation, as `0` will no longer suffice for the type.

Comment: You can [*derive* the instances *via* `State Int`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia): `newtype ST a = .. deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadFix, ..) via State Int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often find it easier to follow such code with a certain type of a pseudocode rewrite, like this: starting with the

```
instance Monad ST where
      return :: a -> ST a
      return x = S (\n -> (x, n))
```

we get to the

```
  runState (return x) n = (x, n)
```

which expresses the same thing exactly. It is now a kind of a *definition through an interaction law* that it must follow. This allows me to ignore the "noise"/wrapping around the essential stuff.

Similarly, then, we have

```
      (>>=) :: ST a -> (a -> ST b) -> ST b
      s >>= f = -- f (fst (runState s 0))   -- nah, 0? what's that?
      -- 
      -- runState (s >>= f) n = runState (f a) i where 
      --                                   (a, i) = runState s n
      --
                S $       \ n ->       let (a, i) = runState s n in
                                runState (f a) i
```

because now we have an `Int` in sight (i.e. in scope), `n`, that *will* get provided to us when the combined computation `s >>= f` will "run". I mean, when it will *`runState`*.

Of course nothing actually runs until called upon from `main`. But it can be a helpful metaphor to hold in mind.

The way we've defined it is both the easiest and the most general, which is usually the way to go. There are more ways to make the types fit though.

One is to use `n` twice, in the input to the second `runState` as well, but this will leave the `i` hanging unused.

Another way is to flip the time arrow around w.r.t. the state passing, with

```
                S $       \ n ->       let (a, i2) = runState s i 
                                           (b, i ) = runState (f a) n
                                        in (b, i2)
```

which is a bit weird to say the least. `s` still runs first (as expected for the `s >>= f` combination) to produce the value `a` from which `f` creates the second computation stage, but the state is being passed around in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing to keep in mind is that your `ST` type is a wrapper around a *function*. What if you started your definition as `(>>=) = \s -> \f -> S (\n -> ... )`? It might be (ok, is) a bit silly to write separate lambdas for the `s` and `f` parameters there, but I did it to show that they're not really any different from the `n` parameter.  You can use it in your definition of `(>>=)`.

Comment: I have tried the following but I have typing error.

(>>=) :: ST a -> (a -> ST b) -> ST b
(>>=) = \s -> \f -> S (runState s)

Comment: Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          (>>=) :: forall a b. ST a -> (a -> ST b) -> ST b
        at Attachment_1617740213.hs:29:12-38
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          (>>=) :: forall a b. ST a -> (a -> ST b) -> ST b
        at Attachment_1617740213.hs:29:12-38
      Expected type: ST b
        Actual type: ST a

Comment: @Nibblex that would be a hint that the implementation is wrong then, wouldn't it?